# .net 4 combobox item reselection

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

When our combobox has a selection chosen we do a action.

However when you reselect it, nothing happens as it is already selected.  This also seems rational-nothings changed, so there is no event.

The problem is that selecting the item launches an action, and what we really want is to be able to re-select the same combobox selection, and have it get called again without selecting something else first.

It is databound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is winforms, you could hook the DropDownClosed event and launch the action from there.

In order to handle cases where the user uses the up/down arrow or typing to change the value, you will probably need to set a flag in the DropDownClosed event to indicate that the selection changed event is to be ignored, then clear this flag in the code that performs the action. In the selection changed event, don't launch the action if this flag is set.

Comment: @user1073944: That's ok, it still has that event (plus DropDownOpened, which could also be handy).

Comment: That actually seems like a reasonable suggestion.  Thanks!